# ASP.NET Core Web Application option is missing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to build a new project in Visual Studio 2019, but I cant find "ASP.NET Core Web Application" in the new project type selection window. I find only "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)".

I have updated Visual Studio and installed every feature from the installer. I downloaded Visual Studio 2017 and can find it there, but in Visual Studio 2019 it is not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Not being from a .NET background, I have a hard time understanding why you have a problem with the options VS 2019 offers you (is it simply the addition of ".NET framework" to the option's name?) If there is a reason to it, please [edit] your question accordingly. (Comments are the wrong spot for this clarification!) Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Microsoft's tutorial for getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-aspnet-core?view=vs-2019), see if that's got anything to help you out.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get .NET Core templates you should

1. Open Visual Studio Installer (press the <kbd>Win</kbd> key and search for it)
2. Click on "Modify"
3. Check "ASP.NET and web development", then scroll to the bottom and check ".NET Core cross-platform development"
4. Click "Modify" in left bottom corner and wait for it to install

Answer (score 0):

It's because Visual Studio changed the name of
**ASP.NET Core Web Application** to **ASP.NET Core Web App**:

[image]

Comment: I seriously doubt OP was unable to determine that "App" now shows instead of "Application".

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar issue. I did have "ASP.NET and web development" and ".NET Core cross-platform development" installed as suggested by @krazors. However, there were no APS.NET Core templates available.

The issue was eventually resolved by rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, the issue was that I was missing the .NET 5.0 SDK.

- First modify Visual Studio from the Visual Studio Installer by removing ASP.NET and Web Development.
- Then install .NET 5.0.
- Last modify Visual Studio again by selecting ASP.NET and Web Development on the Visual Studio Installer.